# Set and Read/Retrieve cookie using javascript within a java file(.java)

Tags: java, javascript, http, sockets, cookies

Let me refrase it. i am writing a new http-server using sockets in java-language(not javascript) and i want to tell client to set cookie. I would like  to do that in javascript(setin reading the cookie). If that is not possible, Are there other solutions?
Thank you all.

Comment: Please rephrase your question!! Are you writing a new server or just using one? Do you want the code in javascript or java?

Comment: If you are writing the server in Java, and not using JavaScript, where does the JavaScript to handle the cookie come into play? Is this client side JavaScript? If so, it renders the server completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Your question/requirement is extremely vague. Are you really not confusing [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) with [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) itself or maybe [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javaserver_pages)? Or are you using server-side JavaScript? Why would you like to do that for a "http server"? Why would you like to write a HTTP server rather than using en existing one like [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org) or [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org)?

At least, in JavaScript you can manage cookies by [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:document.cookie). In Java it depends on in which context you're talking. If in Servlet context, use [`HttpServletResponse#addcookie()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29) and [`HttpServletRequest#getCookies()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29). If in JSP EL context, use [`${cookie}`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij). If in URL streaming context, use [`URLConnection#addRequestProperty()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`URLConnection#getHeaderFields()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFields%28%29). If in "raw" Socket context just adhere the HTTP state management specification [RFC 2965](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.html) and indirectly also the HTTP 1.1 specification [RFC 2616](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html) while writing the "raw" data through the socket. But you should already know that as you intended to create a HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing your own HTTP server, then you should be able to set the HTTP header directly:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

You could also send javascript to the browser to do this (by including your script in a HTML page which you give to the client), but I don't really see the advantage of doing it that way.

The example was taken from the following wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie